# Store user account information on a singleton object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, singleton

I'm building an MVVM Light WPF app in Visual Studio 2015. I've got the following singleton class:

```
public sealed class AppContextSingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<AppContextSingleton> _instance =
        new Lazy<AppContextSingleton>(() => new AppContextSingleton());

    private AppContextSingleton()
    {
    }

    public static AppContextSingleton Instance => _instance.Value;
    public static string UserDisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

In `App.xaml.cs`, I have the following code to authenticate the user and fetch the person's display name from the Active Directory:

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var appContext = AppContextSingleton.Instance;

    // Code to authenticate user goes here...

    var displayName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
}
```

Here, I'd like to set the `UserDisplayName` on the `AppContextSingleton` and later reference it from the public `Instance` property. However, the `Instance` does not give me access to the `UserDisplayName` property. How would I set this property and then access it from `Instance`?

Should I be referencing the `Instance` or `UserDisplayName`? Your help in understanding this is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `UserDisplayName` is a `static` property.

That means it is accessed like this: `AppContextSingleton.UserDisplayName`.

If you change it to an instance property `public string UserDisplayName { get; set; }` it will work like you want.

**Side note 1:** I'd remove the Singleton suffix from `AppContextSingleton`.

**Side note 2:** Since this is WPF you probably want to implement `InotifyPropertyChanged`and notify when the value changes since it is mutable.

**Side note 3:** Does it really need a public set?

Comment: Thanks, @JohanLarsson. #1 is done; will do #2. #3: I set the `UserDisplayName` after the authentication in `App.xaml.cs` startup. Is it possible to have the `set` be private?